# Get Publish Targets in Web 8 with Core Service?

Tags: core-service, web8

I am trying to get the publish targets using Web 8 and Core Service.  The below code works in Tridion 2013 but returns nothing in Web 8.  Do I need a new filter for Web 8?

```
var readoptions = new ReadOptions();
var filter = new PublicationTargetsFilterData();
var allPublicationTargets = Client.GetSystemWideList(filter);
```

Comment: Those are the legacy Publication Targets, do you have them on your system, or are you using Business Process types?

Comment: Using Business Process Types.  Ideally I would like to get a list of TargetTypes from a Business Process Type.

Comment: If you really want publication targets use: new PublicationTargetsFilterData { IncludeEmulated = true } , but with new publishing model we tried to move from the concept of PTs, so we recommend to use TTs. If you want TargetTypes from a Business Process Type you can get them just from BusinessProcessTypeData.TargetTypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the below code to get the new TargetTypes.  Since I only have 1 BusinessProcessType this code works fine for my situation.

```
var readoptions = new ReadOptions();
var filter = new TargetTypesFilterData();
var allPublicationTargets = Client.GetSystemWideList(filter);

foreach (TargetTypeData pubTarget in allPublicationTargets)
{

}
```